# Forcibly logout all other sessions in case of multiple login by same user

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

I have an application where in im preventing multiple login by same user.If user tries to login from another webpage/machine(when already logged in another) then a confirm box appears asking whether he needs to logout the previous session or not,if he clicks "yes" then the previous sessions shud be logged off.Im not able to logout the previous session however the code is preventing multiple login but how can i logoff the previous session n redirect user to main page with present session

Here is the code
In  loginButton_Click(after authentication)

```
    string sKey = loginControl.UserName + loginControl.Password;
    string sUser = Convert.ToString(Cache[sKey]);
    if (sUser == null || sUser == String.Empty || sUser == "")
    {
        TimeSpan SessTimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout, 0, 0);
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(sKey, sKey, null, DateTime.MaxValue, SessTimeOut, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
        Session["user"] = loginControl.UserName + loginControl.Password;
        Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>if(window.confirm('You have already Logged In.Do you want to sign off the previous Session?')){} else{window.location.href='login.aspx'}</script>");
        //if part
        return;
    }
```

In Global.asax page

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        if (Session["user"] != null)
        {
            string sKey = (string)Session["user"];
            string sUser = (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache[sKey];
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in HttpContext.Current.Cache)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove((string)de.Key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use your IDE and the code-button in the editor to [format your code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) properly.

Answer (score 0):

The current approach you are using is problematic. You keep the same "key" ( `loginControl.UserName + loginControl.Password` ) to identify your user's session, Instead of a unique key (`Guid.NewGuid()` for instance) per session.
If you have a unique key, you will be able to distinguish one session from another (e.g. if user performs a login twice, you will be able to know which is which)

**Explaination:**
When a user logs in, create a new Guid and keep it in another Session key (`Session["SessionGuid"] = Guid.NewGuid()` for instance).
In addition either keep a dictionary (or create a separate entry for each user in the global cache) in which per userId you save the unique Guid.
Since in one session you will have the old Guid and in the new session you will have the new Guid, you can check in the `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` which Guid the current session has, and if it doesn't match - disconnect the user.

Comment: Blachshma Thank u so much for the reply.But how to logout/clear previous session (not the present) and continue with the present login.Im a newbie so pls guide.

Comment: The previous session is the one which doesn't match the current Guid